# How do I divide all items in a list

Tags: python, list, division

```
>>> ListOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8 / 9 / 10  # should be computed
2.75573192e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`:

```
ListOfNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x/float(y), ListOfNumbers))
```

Output:

```
2.7557319224e-07
```

You can also use `itertools.accumulate` for Python3:

```
import operator
import itertools
print(list(itertools.accumulate(ListOfNumbers, func=operator.truediv))[-1])
```

Output:

```
2.7557319223985894e-07
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `reduce` the list with a division operation. Note that since all the elements in your list are integers, you'd have to convert them to floats in order to use floating point division and get the result you expect:

```
result = reduce((lambda x, y: float(x) / y), [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Comment: *"you'd have to convert them to floats in order to use floating point division"* - Only in Python 2.